# Swift equivelent for every 'x' press of button to perform action

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Coming from `objective-C` background and just moving slowly into `Swift`, I can use `let` rather than `#define` however how would this statement be translated from `objective-C` to `swift`?

`#define ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY 5` will become `let ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY = 5`

However, how can we translate this below to `swift?`

```
#ifdef ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger nb_shown_lobby = [prefs integerForKey:@"nShownLobby"];
nb_shown_lobby++;
[prefs setInteger:nb_shown_lobby forKey:@"nShownLobby"];
[prefs synchronize];

if ((nb_shown_lobby % ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY) == 0) {
  
   //My Method goes here
    
}

#endif
```

The endgame of the above method is to basically show an action on every 5th press.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use entirely different approach here, such as for instance bundling a plist file that tells your application which features to enable and which to skip. This would be a runtime check but it's not that terrible.

The other way would be to introduce a struct with feature flags and compile the right configuration on per-target basis, i.e:

```
/// FeatureFlagsAbstract.swift
protocol FeatureFlags {
    static var myFeature: Int? { get }
}

/// Target A/Features.swift
struct MyFeatureFlags: FeatureFlags {
    static var myFeature: Int? {
        return 5
    }
}

/// Target B/Features.swift
struct MyFeatureFlags: FeatureFlags {
    static var myFeature: Int? {
        return nil
    }
}


/// Class.swift
class MyClass {
    func doSomething() {
       if let value = MyFeatureFlags.myFeature {
          // branch that uses some feature
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, unfortunately when using the first example (which seems to fit my needs more than the latter code)  I am met with an error

`Expected '&&' or '||' expression`

That is when I use this

`#if ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY > 0

// Do something

#endif`

Comment: @DannyRoy you're right. It looks like swift treats precompiler variables as boolean flags. Either way, the second part of my answer still holds.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the provided replies gave a correct answer, I have since figured out the solution.

```
let ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY = 5
                   
                    let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
                    var nb_shown_lobby = prefs.integer(forKey: "nShownLobby")
                    nb_shown_lobby += 1
                    prefs.set(nb_shown_lobby, forKey: "nShownLobby")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    if (nb_shown_lobby % ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY) == 0 {
                        //Do your method here
                    }
```

Comment: Not quite the same, as the Objective-C code won't execute unless the constant is defined, while the Swift code will always execute.

Answer (score -1):

Has now it is a swift constant it can be processed with swift code :

```
if ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY > 0 { // equivalent to ifdef 
…
} // équivalent to endif
```

To undefined ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY set its value to 0

In case value 0 may be used in other context, you may use optional integer :

```
// let ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY : Int? = 5 
// -> is equivalent to #define myMacro 5
// let ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY : Int? = nil 
// is equivalent to not defining the macro 
// uncomment the line according to what you want to achieve 

usage :

if let _ = ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY {
    …
    if ((nb_shown_lobby % ADS_INTERSTITIAL_ON_LOBBY_FREQUENCY!) == 0) {

   //My Method goes here
    
}
    
}
```

Comment: Is it Java? ......

Comment: @RobZombie  : no it is swift

Comment: This code produces several errors @PtitXav

Comment: Can you tell me ? I am writing from the application and have no mac with Xcode to test.